# how to configure java keystore and trustore for soap https call

Tags: java, soap, https, keystore, truststore

I need to call wsdl over https.

From provider I got `x.p12` file and x.crt file. 
How do I configure java keystore and trustore?

I am using java 1.6 (32 bits).
I set `keystore = x.p12` and imported x.crt in x.jksbut this is not working for me.

This is the code:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\java\\java6u45\\jre\\lib\\security\\x");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\SoapUI (1)\\SoapUI\\x.p12");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "passX!");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");

    URL u = null;
    try {
        u = new URL("https://x1/x2WS/x3?wsdl");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    JobInput2Service service = new JobInput2Service(u);
    JobInput2 job = service.getJobInput2Port();
    try {
        HelloRequestParm parm = new HelloRequestParm();
        parm.setMessage("value");
        HelloResponseData res = job.sayHello(parm);
        System.out.print("\n res: "+res.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)

Comment: Please add code sample of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I put it in the description of the question